# Radon-Nikodym Exercise from Billingsley

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, radon-nikodym

Below is the Exercise 32.6 ( billingsley's probability and measure) from the Section of Radon- Nikodym Theorem.

I have done the question (a) but I am unable to do the other **two parts (b) and (c)**, even though I might have the solution I do not understand it.

[image]

Comment: what means $\nu \equiv \mu $?

Comment: $\nu \equiv \mu$  (i.e., ν << μ and μ  <<ν )

Comment: TeX note.  `\ll` is $\ll$, see the difference from $<<$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (b) note that if $\,\mathrm d \nu =h\,\mathrm d \mu $ and $\,\mathrm d \mu =g \,\mathrm d \nu $ for some $h\in L^1(\mu)$ and some $g\in L^1(\nu)$ then $\,\mathrm d \nu =hg\,\mathrm d \nu $, hence $hg=1$ $\nu $-almost everywhere, what imply that $h=1/g\ $ $\nu$-almost everywhere, what is equivalent to the expression that you want to prove.

Comment: Thank you very much. What about question c ?